# Telegram bot Message Handler error [Local varialbe referenced before assignment]

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from panda import *

from telegram.ext import *
from telegram.update import *


load_dotenv('.env')
Token =os.getenv('TOKEN')

print("The bot connected .....")



# commands handler 


# start message 
def start_command(update,context):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello am mr panda am here to help you: ")

# help command 
def help_command(update,context):
    res = panda.help()

    update.message.reply_text(res)


# message handler 

**def message_handle(update,context):
    message = str(update.message.text).lower()
    respose = panda.hello(message)
    update.message.reply_text(respose)** 

# errror handler 
def error(update,context):
    print(f"Update the context error : {context.error}")


# main function 
def main():
    global message
    updater =Updater(Token,use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # command handlers
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help",help_command))

    **# message handlers
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,message_handle))**

    # error handlers 
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


main()
```

**This was the code Am getting error**

Update the context error: **local variable 'message' referenced before assignment**

I think there is an error on the highlighted portions I do little searches and I referred to the documentation too I can't catch the error.

Does anyone have solution that would be great :)

Comment: Please remove the error handler so that you can see the full traceback.